# How does a (2 or 3) dimensional Fully connected layer work?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I came across a Neural network which had the following configuration:(FCL = Fully connected layer)

- Input Layer - 1 dimensional with 100 units
- 1st layer   - 1 dimensional FCL with 512 units
- 2nd layer   - 3 dimensional FCL with aXbXc size

Now as far as I know, a fully connected layer means that each of its units is connected to each of the units of its previous layer. If that is actually true, how are the connections made with the 2nd FCL which is not single dimensional.
I'm very confused as to how this multi dimensional FCL is working.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the reference architecture?

Comment: Yes sure !
Here it is https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/11/16/gans-with-keras-and-tensorflow/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory - please see the intro and **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aXbXc` doesn't mean that the dense layer has 3 dimensions. It is just a single number obtained by multiplying `a`, `b,` and `c` together to obtain the size of that dense layer.

According to the provided link:

```
model.add(Dense(dim * dim * depth))
```

if `dim` is 10 and `depth` is 20 then the result is `10 * 10 * 20`, which would be the
same as

```
model.add(Dense(2000))
```

Comment: Oh ! I got this now. Thanks alot. Also, now can I say that a FCL can not be multidimensioanal ?

Comment: Well, this is mostly an implementational detail but in general, dense layers are not multidimensional since even if you have multidimensional input to the dense layer, you can always flatten the input and the same goes for the output.